# How to auto hide collection view in Xcode when nothing is to be displayed?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view placed at the bottom of screen, which displays related topics to the data that is being displayed currently on the screen. But, for some cases, there are no related topics. So, the collection view appears, but as no relevant topics are there no cells appear. So, the collection view appears overlapping my data on the screen. Hence, I want to hide the collection view at the bottom automatically when there is no result for the related topic.

Comment: add the code where you detect that there is no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for the help. Found the solution. Just made the hidden property true when the result count is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting the collection view hidden property to YES when model count is 0.

Comment: Just asking @jianzong, I think Collection view hidden property should be YES/TRUE when count is 0. Because I want to hide the collection view when no results are being displayed.